# Unable to connect using ip address from client in simple python socket program

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking, websocket, ip

Honestly, this is lifted more or less from tutorials point networking on python-https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.html
Server program:

```
import socket               # Import socket module
dd="You connected sucessfully to the server"
dd1=bytes(dd,'UTF-8')
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print ('Got connection from', addr)
   c.send(dd1)
   c.close()                # Close the connection
```

Client side:

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)         # Create a socket object
host = '80.78.xxx.xxx' # Get local machine name/value
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print(s.recv(102004))
s.close()                     # Close the socket when done
```

So, I'm able to run it on the same PC and get result. If my understanding of the code is correct, host means localhost. But it should also work when I try to access it using the ip address. But it doesn't. Please help. It returns the error: Error 10060
[https://help.globalscape.com/help/archive/cuteftp6/socket_error_=__10060.htm#:~:text=10060%20is%20a%20Connection%20Time,prefers%20PORT%20for%20data%20connections.&text=ERROR%3A%3E%20Can't%20connect%20to%20remote%20server.](https://help.globalscape.com/help/archive/cuteftp6/socket_error_=__10060.htm#:%7E:text=10060%20is%20a%20Connection%20Time,prefers%20PORT%20for%20data%20connections.&text=ERROR%3A%3E%20Can%27t%20connect%20to%20remote%20server.)
I forwarded the ports 12340 to 12350 to my ip address on the router. Removed all firewall. Yet this happens.

A similar error happend when I tried to put a website up using node.js. Works perfectly on local host but doesn't work when I try to access using public IP address. I'm very confused and would be glad if you pointed to any literature to get a deeper understanding.

Comment: *"But it should also work when I try to access it using the ip address."* - the IP address of localhost is 127.0.0.1, not 80.78.xxx.xxx. Accessing by the external IP requires port forwarding on the router, no firewalls in the path and possible support or NAT hairpinning.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , Sorry I didn't mention in the question. But I did remove all the firewalls. I "switched/turned off" the firewall. I already assigned the port to my ip address.  And am still getting the same problem.  Can you please elaborate on NAT hairpinning?

Comment: I'm  assuming that you are trying to reach an internal system from inside the same network by its external IP address. To do so your NAT router must support [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) - some do and others don't.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich wow, great info thanks. Final question, if the client is running on a different Router altogether with another ISP, will it work?

Comment: In this case NAT hairpinning irrelevant.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich hey, I checked my router. And it supports NAT hairpinning. I am still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on then. The code you show is fine. Thus there must be something wrong which you don't show. You can try to narrow down the problem by doing packet captures (for example using Wireshark) to see the outgoing and incoming packets and check these against your expectations.